# Repeater DataItem is null

Tags: c#, .net

```
rptABC.DataSource = ListOfXYZClass;
rptABC.DataBind();

List<XYZClass> selectedItems = rptABC
                                 .Items
                                 .Cast<RepeaterItem>()
                                 .Where(x => ((CheckBox)x.FindControl("cbSelect")).Checked)
                                 .Select(u => (XYZClass)u.DataItem)
                                 .ToList();
```

I do select 2 from repeater and result is that selectedItems has 2 items and both null, how can I get ListOfXYZClass which are selected

Comment: After postback the `DataSource` is `null` and also every item's `DataItem`.

Comment: any suggestion how to get Items after postback?

Comment: you could store it somewhere else(f.e. `Session`), but you should do not. Why polluting the memory with potentially outdated objects or create race conditions? Store what you need to identify it(f.e. the ID). You can use a control in the repateritem or a `CommandArgument` of a `Button`. Then, if you really need the orginal datasource after postback, load it again from the database (or whatever you use). In this case, why you do need a `List<XYZClass>` at all? I guess that it's sufficient to know which ID's were selected.

Comment: I am showing selecteds in another grid. I get them from DB. thanks!